# Difference between regression tree and model tree

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I need some help in understanding the difference between regression trees and linear model tree.

Regards

Shahzad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A linear model tree is a decision tree with a linear functional model in each leaf, whereas in classical regression tree (e.g., CART) it is the sample mean of the response variable for statistical units in each leaf (hence, a constant) that is being considered. Linear model trees can be seen as a a form of locally weighted regression, while regression tree are piecewise-constant regression.

For more information on linear model trees, you can consult

> Torgo, L. [Functional models for regression tree
>   leaves](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.1587).
>   In *Proceedings of the 14th International Conference on Machine
>   Learning*, pp. 385–393. Morgan Kaufmann, 1997.

Comment: Thanks alot for the exact answer. Are there any software or package available that I can use to construct linear model trees specially in R. Others will also be helpful.

Comment: @Shahzad Take a look at the [Cubist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cubist/index.html) package. Otherwise, you can try Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines (MARS), see [ESLII](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), §9.4.

Comment: I did some analysis with both the packages. With earth package, I get the warning that the model is Intercept only model so I cannot plot it with plotmo. Is there any possibility that I can plot the model generated by Cubist package?